# Activemq JmsTemplate JMSDeliveryTime Error

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, activemq-classic

Good day,
I am new to ActiveMQ and trying to learn, but I am getting this error when I use JMSDeliveryTime to delay my messages before publishing. Anyone came across this error please help. I searched for similar topics and i noticed people saying it is because of JMS 2.0 but it is not saying that. I am using ActiveMQ classic.

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTextMessage does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract void setJMSDeliveryTime(long)' of interface javax.jms.Message.
    at com.activemq.poc5.ProducerResource$1.postProcessMessage(ProducerResource.java:38) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.lambda$convertAndSend$6(JmsTemplate.java:682) ~[spring-jms-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.doSend(JmsTemplate.java:604) ~[spring-jms-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.lambda$send$2(JmsTemplate.java:577) ~[spring-jms-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:504) ~[spring-jms-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:576) ~[spring-jms-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.convertAndSend(JmsTemplate.java:680) ~[spring-jms-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at com.activemq.poc5.ProducerResource.publish(ProducerResource.java:35) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:879) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar:9.0.36]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at
```

The API call i am sending

```
    @GetMapping("/{message}")
    public String publish(@PathVariable("message")
            final String message) {

        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
           // jmsTemplate.setPriority(2);
//            jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(queue, message); //this method sends the given object to the queue destination, converting the object to JMS message
           jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(queue, message, new MessagePostProcessor() {
               @Override
               public Message postProcessMessage(Message msg) throws JMSException {
                   msg.setJMSDeliveryTime(20000);
                   return msg;
               }
           });
           
        }
        return "Published Successfully";
    }
```

Comment: From the error message itself it's clear that activemq implementation class available in your classpath do not confirm to the interface in use by spring's JMSTemplate. If you can also attach your POM than giving out a pointer will be easier.

Comment: In my POM file i only have the spring starter web dependency and spring starter activemq dependency. Regarding my implementation class the JMSTemplate is working but for using a deliveryDelay i get this error. If i only publish a message it works fine. In addition, i tried the priority and it also worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true that the error message doesn't *explicitly* say that the problem is an incompatibility with JMS 2, but that *is* actually the issue. ActiveMQ 5.x (i.e. "classic") only implements JMS 1.1. It doesn't implement JMS 2.0. The method `setJMSDeliveryTime` was added in JMS 2.0. Therefore you can't use `setJMSDeliveryTime` with the ActiveMQ 5.x client.

In a comment you say you're using the `spring-boot-starter-activemq` dependency. This dependency explicitly excludes the JMS 1.1 API:

```xml
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <artifactId>geronimo-jms_1.1_spec</artifactId>
          <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
```

And instead it includes the Jakarta version:

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jakarta.jms</groupId>
      <artifactId>jakarta.jms-api</artifactId>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

The version of this dependency is [2.0.3](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.3.1.RELEASE/pom) which supports JMS 2.0. This means the JMS API version is not actually compatible with the ActiveMQ 5.x client and this is the reason your IDE and/or compiler doesn't complain that you're using an unsupported method (i.e. `setJMSDeliveryTime`).

I recommend you either remove the JMS 2.0 API from your classpath (e.g. using your own `<excludes>` in your Maven dependency) so you can catch these kinds of errors at build time at which point you could leverage something like ActiveMQ's [scheduled message](https://activemq.apache.org/delay-and-schedule-message-delivery) functionality **or** move to a client/broker that actually supports JMS 2.0 like [ActiveMQ Artemis](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/).

If you choose to stick with ActiveMQ 5.x and use its scheduled message functionality then your application won't function properly if you move to a different JMS broker in the future since the properties used by ActiveMQ 5.x to implement the scheduled message functionality are *unique* to ActiveMQ. However, if move to a broker that supports JMS 2.0 and use the standard `setJMSDeliveryTime` then your application will be able to work on *any* broker which supports JMS 2.0.

Comment: Thank you Justin for your detailed answer, it is much appreciated. I am planning to work on the classic version as a start to get familiar with ActiveMQ, afterwards i will move to the Artemis version. Can you please give me a breif answer regarding the difference between using scheduled message and JMSDeliveryTime as i noticed they serve the same purpose then i do not really need to worry about JMS API version.

Comment: I updated my answer to address your question. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by using ScheduledMessage instead of JMSDeliveryDelay

```
    jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(queue, message, new MessagePostProcessor() {
        @Override
        public Message postProcessMessage(Message msg) throws JMSException {
            msg.setLongProperty(ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY, 10000);
            return msg;
        }
    });
}
```